# unable to connect MSSQL using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have already looked up a lot of some what similar questions on StackOverflow regarding the connectivity of MSSQL with pyodbc, but none of their solutions helped. 
I'm tring to connect a MSSQL database which is lying on a VM server, and I'm trying to access it from my local system. 
 Following is the code:

```
import pyodbc

server = '172.xxx.xxx.xxx,1443'
database = 'sample_db'
username = 'SA'
password = 'xxxxx'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.databases;")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

If there's any other alternative to pyodbc that works better with MSSQL, please do mention that too.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**:

Upon @GordThompson suggestion I checked the driver in `pyodbc.drivers()` and found that my system only has 'SQL Server' driver so I changed the Driver to SQL Server. The present code looks like this:

```
import pyodbc
server = '172.xxx.xxx.xxx,1443'
database = 'sample_db'
username = 'SA'
password = 'xxxxx'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.databases;")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

But now i'm getting a totally different error, still not sure what it is 
Error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
```

Comment: is your `.odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` set? --> http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html

Comment: @aws_apprentice Hi, I just installed the mssql on ubuntu in a VM. I didn't do anything with any of the `.ini` files. What exactly am i supposed to do/change here?

Comment: look at the link, that explains it much better than I can in a comment

Comment: @aws_apprentice there's no info about mssql in that link

Comment: @AmanSingh theres info on how to configure those files, that link is agnostic to DBs, read again...

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: @GordThompson it says `SQL Server` but even after putting Driver as SQL Server, I'm still getting an error as `pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')`

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL Server instance has TCP/IP enabled, is listening on port 1443, and the machine on which it is running allows external inbound connections to that port?

Comment: In addition to what @GordThompson said, you should also review what type of authentication you're using. You have UID and PWD set, but you also have `Trusted_Connection=yes` which means both the UID and PWD keys are being ignored. The way you have it set up now it will not be using the account you specified which might be part of the access denied issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its important to not mention the `Trusted_Connection` parameter when logging-in using `UID` and `PWD`. Hence, when I removed the `Trusted_Connection` parameter, it was able to establish the connection successfully.
So the connection string that later worked for me just had these,

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

[ Since @GordThompson didn't post it as an answer, I'm positing it here and closing it.
 Thanks @GordThompson ]